# Strapi V4: Create a plugin that inject a button inside the header of the component edit view

Tags: javascript, plugins, strapi

I would like to inject a button in a specific area using the injectComponent() method provided (see documentation https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/plugins/admin-panel-api#injection-zones-api). The idea is to create a button that can duplicate the selected component. When clicking on this button, a new component would be added with the same data as the one where this button is

I can't find an exhaustive list of the arguments that can be passed as a parameter to this injectComponent() method. So I don't really know which areas can be specified and I would like to know if it is possible to target the area where I would like to add my button (cf. screenshot).

The code would look like this :

```js
// src/plugins/duplicate-component/admin/src/index.js
import DuplicateButton from "./components/DuplicateButton";
export default {
  (...)
    bootstrap(app) {
      app.injectComponent("editView", "editViewComponents", {
        name: "DuplicateButton",
        Component: DuplicateButton,
      });
  (...)
}
```

Srapi Version : 4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuGvu.png)

I tried to follow the Strapi documentation to implement a new button inject in the Compoent EditView of Strapi BackOffice. I tried the `injectContentManagerComponent()` method that provide predefined injection zones. It works well.
As i said, i would like to target a specific zone that is not provided but the `injectContentManagerComponent()`. Example :

```js
    app.injectContentManagerComponent('editView', 'informations', {
      name: 'my-plugin-my-compo',
      Component: () => 'my-compo',
    });
```

So i choose to use the method that allow us to target a specific zone and it did not work even if targeting predefined existing zone :

```js
  app.getPlugin('my-plugin').injectComponent('editView', 'right-links', {
      name: 'my-other-plugin-component',
      Component: () => 'This component is injected',
    });
  }
```